# On the App Store of my Macbook Pro, the top buttons are no longer visible

Tags: mac-appstore

I have a notification that there are updates to install, so as usual, I would like to review them beforehand.

However, when I open the App Store app, I only see the following:
[image: App Store with top buttons missing]

Normally it would say something like "Featured", "Installed", "Updates" and the such. However, now it's all gone! How can I re-enable the display of the buttons?

EDIT: It should normally look like this (notice the buttons in the top bar):
[image: Correct App store display]

Comment: Maybe they're applications that were installed using a different Apple ID?

Comment: No, I mean the entire upper panel of buttons/sections of the App Store are gone.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you on? - this doesn't look like Mojave, but must be some older version?

Comment: I'm on High Sierra... I don't want to upgrade, I want to stay put. I just want the App Store buttons to appear again.

Comment: What if anything have you done to resolve it? Quit and relaunched? Rebooted? Deleted some preference files? Etc.

Comment: A reboot has fixed the problem, but I was really hoping not to have to (I had a LOT of things open and shutting them down and then reopening them is a pain).